# How to use Python's HTMLParser to extract specific links

Tags: python, parsing, hyperlink, web-crawler, html-parsing

I've been working on a basic web crawler in Python using the HTMLParser Class. I fetch my links with a modified handle_starttag method that looks like this:

```
def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    if tag == 'a':
        for (key, value) in attrs:
            if key == 'href':
                newUrl = urljoin(self.baseUrl, value)
                self.links = self.links + [newUrl]
```

This worked very well when I wanted to find **every** link on the page. Now I only want to fetch certain links.

How would I go about only fetching links that are between the `<td class="title">` and `</td>` tags, like this:

```
<td class="title"><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a><span class="comhead"> (arstechnica.com) </span></td>
```

Comment: check if the tag has a parent whose class name is title !

Comment: how do you recommend doing this?

Comment: Have you checked out the Python lxml library? It can parse links and other elements on a page pretty efficiently. http://lxml.de/

Comment: No I haven't, I'll check it out. There's gotta be a way to do it using the HTMLParser class though. I can't seem to find much information on the handle_starttag method anywhere.

Comment: i would use beautifulsoup :) do you want me to post the solution wrt BeautifulSoup ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTMLParser is a SAX-style or streaming parser, which means that you get pieces of the document as they are parsed, but not the whole document at once. The parser calls methods you provide to handle tags and other types of data. Any context you may be interested in, such as which tags are inside other tags, you must glean from the tags you see passing by.

For example, if you see a `<td>` tag, then you know you are in a table cell, and can set a flag to that effect. When you see `</td>`, you know you have left a table cell and can clear that flag. (Actually, you want to use a counter rather than a simple flag to allow nesting of tables, but we'll let that slide).

To get the links inside a table cell, then, if you see `<a>` and you know that you are in a table cell (because of that flag you set), you grab the value of the tag's `href` attribute if it has one.

```py
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class LinkExtractor(HTMLParser):

    def reset(self):
        HTMLParser.reset(self)
        self.extracting = False
        self.links      = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == "td" or tag == "a":
            attrs = dict(attrs)   # save us from iterating over the attrs
        if tag == "td" and attrs.get("class", "") == "title":
            self.extracting = True
        elif tag == "a" and "href" in attrs and self.extracting:
            self.links.append(attrs["href"])

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == "td":
            self.extracting = False
```

This quickly gets to be a pain as you need more and more context to get what you want from the document, which is why people are recommending `lxml` and `BeautifulSoup`. These are DOM-style parsers that keep track of the document hierarchy for you and provide various friendly ways to navigate it, such as a DOM API, XPath, and/or CSS selectors.

BTW, I answered a similar question recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9404495/416467).

Comment: I'd upvote twice if I could for suggesting to use `dict(attr)` instead of a dumb `for` with an `if` inside like in every other post.