# anchor tag HREF extraction

Tags: python, html-parsing

How do you extract the anchor tag attribute (i.e. href value) using Python and HTMLParser module.

e.g. I have HTML code and I need to parse it and find the value of anchor tag using the text.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where did your code fail?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I get href links from html code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075550/how-can-i-get-href-links-from-html-code)

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694769/how-to-use-pythons-htmlparser-to-extract-specific-links) on Stack Overflow shows how to extract links with HTMLParser.

But a more convenient way is to use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075550/how-can-i-get-href-links-from-html-code) shows a way to do just that. Have a look at the documentation of BeautifulSoup if you wish to do more advanced scraping of HTML content.